# Why doesn't this regex match in ruby but matches in any other language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

The following works on `Rubular.com` but doesn't seem to match in ruby:

**The string:**

```
str = "<em>really</em>inexpensive"
```

**Objective:**
Add a space after any closing tag without any space after it.

**The regex**:

```
str.gsub("/(<\/[a-zA-Z]+>)(\S)/","\1 \2")
```

It should give back `"<em>really</em> inexpensive"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use regular expression literal (`/.../`), not string (`"..."`). And escape the `\` in the replacement string. (I used single-quote version of string in the following example)

```
str = "<em>really</em>inexpensive"
str.gsub(/(<\/[a-zA-Z]+>)(\S)/, '\1 \2') # '\1 \2' == "\\1 \\2"
# => "<em>really</em> inexpensive"
```

Comment: Been beating my head over this for an hour. :) Thanks!